# Regex to find text in .xml

Tags: regex, xml, windows, file, nodes

I need to modify a text inside an XML node .. There are more than 1300 files, and the content within this node is variable, I'm having trouble to create the regular expression to find these files, and replace the content inside this node.

The node would be the following:

```
<VDesc> 9:32 </ vDesc>
<VDesc> 1:44 </ vDesc>
<VDesc> 12:25 </ vDesc>
<VDesc> 0:00 </ vDesc>
```

And so it goes...

The value inside this node is variable as you can see.

How would the regular expression for that? Or anyone have any other suggestions?

Thank you

PS: Which tool suggest me for this, for windows.

Comment: What do you want to achieve? The end result? Just set to another, hard-coded, time value? If you just want to set `VDesc` node text to some hard-coded value, just use XSLT.

Comment: Yes i need to modify for 0:00 in all files at once...

Comment: I would definitely avoid regex if possible, and look at Powershell. You can use Xpath queries to find all the nodes called `VDesc`, then modify them.

Comment: Note: I love regexes, they're extremely powerful, but from my point of view they're not the best at this particular job. For me, the combination "XML", "Scripting" and "Windows" leads to Powershell.

Comment: Any solution using regexes will be incorrect; for example it will fail to match elements that have whitespace or comments or CDATA sections in legitimate but unexpected places. It's possible that none of the situations that cause it to be incorrect arise in your 1300 input files, especially if they were generated using a machine process. But how will you know? Better to use a safe technique like XSLT or XQuery.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solve the problem with the follow:

**I use Notepad ++**

Option: "***Search***->***Replace***, then tab ***Find in Files***", in ***Find what*** field i put:

```
<vICMSDeson>(\s*\d+\.\d+\s*)<\/vICMSDeson>
```

, then in Replace with field i put:

```
<vICMSDeson>0.00</vICMSDeson>
```

, in ***Filters*** field i put: *.xml to look only in xml files, then in ***Directory*** i locate the directory i must to search, in ***Search mode*** i select "Regular expression". Job done perfect.

Maybe this is useful for someone else.

Thank you guys

Answer (score 4):

You are having trouble with regular expressions because they are the wrong tool for the job, for a multitude of reasons.

As a matter of principle: If you work with XML, use XML-aware tools.

One of the XML-aware tools that is available on Windows out of the box is the [System.XML namespace](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml(v=vs.110).aspx) of the .NET framework. It's straight-forward to use from a Powershell script.

```
$path = "C:\Path\to\your.xml"
$doc = [xml](Get-Content $path)  # -> System.Xml.XmlDocument

$nodes = $doc.SelectNodes("//VDesc")

foreach ($node in $nodes) {      # -> System.Xml.XmlElement
    # modify/output the node in whatever way you need
    Write-Host $node.InnerText
}

# save changes if necessary
$doc.Save($path)
```

I'll leave as an exercise to make a loop over your files out of that.

Answer (score 1):

Whenever possible, use XML-aware tools to manipulate XML.

My preferred tool is the [BaseX](http://basex.org/)  XML database. Download the windows GUI distribution, load the XML file, then modifying the XML is as trivial as this fragment of XQuery:

```
for $node in //VDesc return replace value of node $node with "0:00"
```

To extract the XML again you have plenty of options - you can read the manual for that.

Answer (score 0):

You need to be more specific but if you want to extract 9:32 From `<VDesc> 9:32 </ vDesc>`

You can use this regex `/<VDesc>(\s*\d+:\d+\s*)<\/ vDesc>/g`. [Example there](https://regex101.com/r/pR6xR1/1)

Note that you'll capture the space if you use \s inside the ().

Comment: Its simple, i only need to modify a value inside a xml node in 1300 files at once, whatever the value in inside this node. I need to modify to 0.00 in all files.

Any suggestion?